# Push WebAPI + IndexedDB + ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I've implemented the Push WebAPI in my web application using Service Worker as many articles explain on the web.
Now I need to store some data inside IndexedDB to make them available while the web app is closed (chrome tab closed, service worker in background execution).
In particular I would like to store a simple url from where retrieve the notification data (from server).

Here is my code:

```
    self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
    console.log("[serviceWorker] Push message received", event);

    notify({ event: "push" }); // This notifies the push service for handling the notification

    var open = indexedDB.open("pushServiceWorkerDb", 1);
    open.onsuccess = () => {
        var db = open.result;
        var tx = db.transaction("urls");
        var store = tx.objectStore("urls");
        var request = store.get("fetchNotificationDataUrl");

        request.onsuccess = (ev) => {
            var fetchNotificationDataUrl = request.result;
            console.log("[serviceWorker] Fetching notification data from ->", fetchNotificationDataUrl);

            if (!(!fetchNotificationDataUrl || fetchNotificationDataUrl.length === 0 || !fetchNotificationDataUrl.trim().length === 0)) {
                event.waitUntil(
                    fetch(fetchNotificationDataUrl, {
                        credentials: "include"
                    }).then((response) => {
                        if (response.status !== 200) {  
                            console.log("[serviceWorker] Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: " + response.status);
                            throw new Error();
                        }

                        return response.json().then((data) => {
                            if (!data) {
                                console.error("[serviceWorker] The API returned no data. Showing default notification", data);
                                //throw new Error();
                                showDefaultNotification({ url: "/" });
                            }

                            var title = data.Title;
                            var message = data.Message;
                            var icon = data.Icon;
                            var tag = data.Tag;
                            var url = data.Url;

                            return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                                body: message,
                                icon: icon,
                                tag: tag,
                                data: {
                                    url: url
                                },
                                requireInteraction: true
                            });
                        });
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.error("[serviceWorker] Unable to retrieve data", err);

                        var title = "An error occurred";
                        var message = "We were unable to get the information for this push message";
                        var icon = "/favicon.ico";
                        var tag = "notification-error";
                        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                            body: message,
                            icon: icon,
                            tag: tag,
                            data: {
                                url: "/"
                            },
                            requireInteraction: true
                        });
                    })
                );
            } else {
                showDefaultNotification({ url: "/" });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Unfortunately when I receive a new push event it doesn't work, showing this exception:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished.
>       at IDBRequest.request.onsuccess (https://192.168.0.102/pushServiceWorker.js:99:23)

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial call to `event.waitUntil()` needs to be done synchronously when the event handler is first invoked. You can then pass in a promise chain to `event.waitUntil()`, and inside that promise chain, carry out any number of asynchronous actions.

Your current code invokes an asynchronous IndexedDB callback before it calls `event.waitUntil()`, which is why you're seeing that error.

The easiest way to include IndexedDB operations inside a promise chain is to use a wrapper library, like [`idb-keyval`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval), which takes the callback-based IndexedDB API and converts it into a promise-based API.

Your code could then look like:

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  // Call event.waitUntil() immediately:
  event.waitUntil(
    // You can chain together promises:
    idbKeyval.get('fetchNotificationDataUrl')
      .then(url => fetch(url))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => self.registration.showNotification(...)
  );
});
```

Comment: For ones interested I've used self.importScripts('/libs/idb-keyval/dist/idb-keyval-min.js'); to use idb-keyval from service worker